# find a representation for the bounded liner functionals in l^p where p belongs t0 [1, infinity)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

For a representation for a bounded linear functionals in L^p, I see we have Riesz's Representation. But how can we find a representation for the bounded linear functionals in l^p for p in [1, infinity)? Someone showed me a representation, but it looked so complicated and big which I didn't understand at all! So, Please I need help!

Also, I don't understand what's the difference between Lp and lp? How the representation will be different from each other in both spaces?

Answer (score 1):

For $x^{\ast}\in(l^{p})^{\ast}$, $p\in[1,\infty)$, let $\beta_{j}=x^{\ast}(e_{j})$, one checks that $x^{\ast}(\alpha)=\displaystyle\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}x^{\ast}e_{j}=\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}\beta_{j}$. It suffices to show that $\beta=(\beta_{j})\in l^{q}$.

Find a $\gamma_{j}$ such that $|\gamma_{j}|=1$ and $|\beta_{j}|=\gamma_{j}\beta_{j}$, then for $1<p<\infty$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j}^{k}|\beta_{j}|^{q}&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\gamma_{j}\beta_{j}|\beta_{j}|^{q-1}\\
&=x^{\ast}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\gamma_{j}|\beta_{j}|^{q-1}e_{j}\right)\\
&\leq\|x^{\ast}\|\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{k}\gamma_{j}|\beta_{j}|^{q-1}e_{j}\right\|_{p}\\
&=\|x^{\ast}\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}|\beta_{j}|^{q}\right)^{1/p},
\end{align*}
now taking $k\rightarrow\infty$ to conclude.

For $p=1$, we have $|\beta_{j}|=|x^{\ast}(e_{j})|\leq\|x^{\ast}\|\|e_{j}\|_{1}=\|x^{\ast}\|$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction!

Comment: To be honest, I don't even understand what this question is asking for.. what actually it means to give a "representation"? Can you explain it with words like what we are looking for in these representation? (ps: Suppose I have very little knowledge about these type of math)

Comment: In some sense, it is that for every $x^{\ast}\in (l^{p})^{\ast}$, the bounded linear functional on $l^{p}$, you need to find a corresponding sequence $\beta=(\beta_{j})$ such that $x^{\ast}(\alpha)=x^{\ast}((\alpha_{j}))=\displaystyle\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}\beta_{j}$, so the action of $x^{\ast}$ is represented by the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{j}(\cdot)_{j}\beta_{j}$ by the sequence $\beta$.